# a confusion about calling super class method in scala

Tags: java, scala

this is my Scala code, I will paste it first

```
abstract class Item {
  def price(): Double
  def descript(): String
} 

class SimpleItem(var price: Double, var descript: String) extends Item

class Bundle(price: Double, descript: String, var other: Item) 
  extends SimpleItem(price, descript) {

  override def price = other.price + super.price
  override def descript = "this item can contain other item,and now it's containning:"+
    other.descript
}
```

in method price of `Bundle`, when I use `super.price`, the compiler thinks I use the private attribute of the super class, but when I change it to `super.price()`, now the compiler thinks I add `()` to `Double`. Now I am confused: Is there another way to call super class's method?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069465/simple-scala-getter-setter-override

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sad truth is that scala does not allow you to override the getter nor the setter of a var.
This conflicts with the uniform access principle (and contrasts with `val`s, which you can override) but you'll have to live with this restriction.

A (somewhat ugly) work around is to define a getter and setter yourself, like this:

```
class SimpleItem(private var _price: Double, private var _descript: String) extends Item{
  def price = _price
  def price_=( value: Double ) { _price = value }
  def descript = _descript
  def descript_=( value: String ) { _descript = value }
}
```

`SimpleItem` is still functionally equivalent to your orignal version, and you can now override the setters and getters (now your `Bundle` class will compile fine as is).

Comment: Note that you should be aware of a notable difference with my revised version of `SimpleItem`: when instantiating it with by name parameters, you'll have to use the ugly `_price` name isntead of hust `price.
In other words, you'll have to do this: `new SimpleItem(_price = 123, _description = "foo") instead of `new SimpleItem(price = 123, description = "foo")`.
Otherwise both versions are strictily interchangeable.

Comment: but I think SimpleItem already have the method because it inheritance from Item.

Comment: The issue is that scala won't let you a concrete var matter what. The change I did was to define explicit getters and setters, which you can override without any problem.
Yes, `SimpleItem` already inherits the `price` abstract method (and even implements it through its `price` var). But because `price` now is a `var`, the scala compiler won't let you override it further in the derived classes. 
This may be a baffling restriction, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: You will often see `price0`, `descript0` as constructor argument names. That's not exactly more pretty than `_price`, but it indicates that these are initial values for an otherwise variable parameter.