# How to provide ambiguous reference in scala inherit trait?

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have trait, this trait is already defined in framework and can not change:

```
trait GenericProfile {
def firstName: Option[String]
def lastName: Option[String]
def fullName: Option[String]
def email: Option[String]
def avatarUrl: Option[String]
}
```

I want a class inherit it as:

```
class BasicProfile(
providerId: String,
userId: String,
firstName: Option[String],
lastName: Option[String],
fullName: Option[String],
email: Option[String],
avatarUrl: Option[String]
) extends GenericProfile{
def providerId=this.providerId  //ambiguous reference will be here
...
}
```

But if I do not re-define the unimplemented method, there is still error since the value in BasicProfile is regarded as private and do not regard it as already implemented.

I understand that it can simply write as override, but I have another class in practice:

```
case class IdProfile(id:String,
providerId: String,
userId: String,
firstName: Option[String],
lastName: Option[String],
fullName: Option[String],
email: Option[String],
avatarUrl: Option[String])extends BasicProfile(providerId,userId,firstName,lastName,  fullName,email, avatarUrl){

}
```

I do not want the IdProfile override the methods from its parents class BasicProfile, just inherit would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BasicProfile has to make sure all that the defined methods of the `trait` are implemented (since you don't want to use an abstract class), I'd recommend using a `case class` for the BasicProfile.

You can extend the BasicProfile with an IdProfile `class` (not `case class`) and override the specific methods you are interesed in (or leave them be). If I'm not mistaken that's what your trying to accomplish?

```
trait GenericProfile {
  def firstName: Option[String]
  def lastName: Option[String]
  def fullName: Option[String]
  def email: Option[String]
  def avatarUrl: Option[String]
}
```

```
case class BasicProfile(
  providerId: String,
  userId: String,
  var firstName: Option[String],
  var lastName: Option[String],
  var fullName: Option[String],
  var email: Option[String],
  var avatarUrl: Option[String]
) extends GenericProfile{
}
```

```
class IdProfile(id:String,
  providerId: String,
  userId: String,
  firstName: Option[String],
  lastName: Option[String],
  fullName: Option[String],
  email: Option[String],
  avatarUrl: Option[String])extends BasicProfile(providerId,userId,firstName,lastName,  fullName,email, avatarUrl){
}
```

If you are trying to stay away from `case class` I'd recommend taking a look at this Question: [Simple Scala getter/setter override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069465/simple-scala-getter-setter-override)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To define a readable field in the argument list to a class's constructor, you can use `val`:

```
class BasicProfile(
  val providerId: String,
  val firstName: Option[String],
  ...
) extends GenericProfile {
  ...
}
```

When you do not put `val` (or alternatively `var` for a mutable field) on the constructor argument, a field is generally not created.

If you define your class as a case class, then constructor arguments without modifiers are treated as if they have `val` in front of them, and fields are created for them:

```
case class BasicProfile(
  providerId: String,
  ...
) extends GenericProfile {
  ...
}
```